# displaying original args after localizing $0

Tags: perl, ubuntu, centos, ps, argv

When run with arguments `a b c d e f g`, this script:

```
system("ps ww$$");
{
  local $0 = "foo";
  system("ps ww$$");
}
system("ps ww$$");
```

prints something like:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
16057 pts/5    S+     0:00 perl /tmp/u a b c d e f g
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
16057 pts/5    S+     0:00 foo
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
16057 pts/5    S+     0:00 /tmp/u
```

In other words, in the third case `ps` does not display the original argv array.

Is there a way that the original args (e.g. `a b c d e f g`) can be restored / displayed via `ps`?

I'm using Centos and Ubuntu.

Comment: I can reproduce using 5.14.0. It's probably not fixed in 5.14.1 or 5.14.2. Bugs should be reported using the `perlbug` command line tool.

Comment: It's still not fixed with 5.22.0 (tried on a Linux Mint system).

Answer (score 1):

place the following at the top of your program:

```
$0 = "perl $0 @ARGV";
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  I just tried something similar, showing the value of `$0` before invoking `ps`.

Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$| = 1;

print "\$0 = $0\n";
system 'ps', "ww$$";
print "\n";

{
    local $0 = 'foo';
    print "\$0 = $0\n";
    system 'ps', "ww$$";
    print "\n";
}

print "\$0 = $0\n";
system 'ps', "ww$$";
```

and here's the output (the first `$` is a shell prompt):

```
$ ./foo.pl
$0 = ./foo.pl
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 2478 pts/2    S+     0:00 /usr/bin/perl ./foo.pl

$0 = foo
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 2478 pts/2    S+     0:00 foo

$0 = ./foo.pl
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 2478 pts/2    S+     0:00 ./foo.pl
```

So `$0` is restored to its original value, but the information printed by `ps` is different.

Note that @EricStrom's workaround doesn't quite have the (presumably) intended result; it makes `ps` show the command name as `perl`, not `/usr/bin/perl` (the latter could be useful information).

It appears that Perl is attempting to restore `$0` to its original value, but it doesn't quite succeed in restoring the information shown by `ps`.

I think the bottom line is that modifying `$0` can be useful, but the behavior is not 100% reliable or portable.

[`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) says:

> On some (but not all) operating systems assigning to $0 modifies the
>   argument area that the ps program sees. On some platforms you may have
>   to use special ps options or a different ps to see the changes.
>   Modifying the $0 is more useful as a way of indicating the current
>   program state than it is for hiding the program you're running.

Comment: I suppose you could use `$0 = "$^X $0 @ARGV"` to capture the exact path of the perl interpreter

Comment: @user5402: Yes, but if you invoke it with `perl foo.pl`, then `ps` *doesn't* show the full path to the Perl interpreter.